# Externally query a vim server to list the open buffers in it

Tags: buffers, clientserver

I'm on linux and I'm querying the list of files open in a gvim server so I can pull it up with

```
gvim --servername <name> --remote <file>
```

To do so, I wrote a helper function that returns buffers

```
function! returnbufferlist()
    execute "silent redir @m"
    execute "silent buffers"
    execute "silent redir END"
    "execute "<ESC><ESC>"
    let a=@m
    return a
endfunction
```

My external script loops through all gvim servers, and runs

```
gvim --remote-expr 'returnbufferlist()'
```

I check my filename against the list of buffers, and if it's open in the server, I run

```
gvim --servername <name> --remote <file>
```

as above. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is there a dbus interface that allows me to do the same thing more efficiently? Now I'm doing some regex matching that's trying to match my filename with the bufferlist, and this doesn't always work as intended since buffers are not listed with full paths.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your own code to list the buffers, instead of `execute "silent buffers"`:

```
for i in range(1, bufnr('$'))
  if buflisted(i)
    echo i . ' ' . fnamemodify(bufname(i), ':p')
  endif
endfor
```

Here `fnamemodify()` with `':p'` will give you the full path to each filename.

The check for `&buflisted` will avoid listing buffers which have been closed, help buffers, and other buffers which have unlisted themselves, such as the MiniBufExplorer plugin.

Comment: That's great, but I think you meant `endif` instead of `fi`.

Comment: As an aside, `buflisted(i)` and `getbufvar(i, '&buflisted')` are equivalent but the former is shorter ([`:help buflisted()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#buflisted%28%29) for details). On the other hand, [`fnameescape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#fnameescape%28%29) could also be useful when filenames contain special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the {correc,sugges}tions @JairLópez. I have incorporated some of them. Whether to use `fnameescape()` really depends on how he handles the filenames next. (It might be easier without it, but you are right that really it is safer to use it, e.g. for those pesky filenames containing newlines!)